# Custom REST Service HTTPS error

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am building an apex REST service to be hosted on a public site using the approach outlined here (basically hosting a REST service on a site allows you to perform actions against it without authentication, which is nice for javascript integration).

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

My service works perfectly in Sandbox, but when attempting to access it in prod, it always throws

```
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <errorCode>UNSUPPORTED_CLIENT</errorCode>
        <message>HTTPS Required</message>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

This error happens even when accessing the service via HTTPs.

Here is my functional sandbox one
https://fpitesters.testbed.cs7.force.com/webServices/services/apexrest/respondentPortal/

You will get an auth token error there, that is expected. It's just a basic security measure.

And here is the production one
https://fpitesters.force.com/webServices/services/apexrest/respondentPortal/

**UPDATE:** So as Josh Birk pointed out, you do need to use the secure sub domain. If you try to just use HTTPs on the regular URL you do get redirected to a regular http domain. So with that in mind, the url for my service should be

https://fpitesters.secure.force.com/webServices/services/apexrest/respondentPortal/

However that URL says that the service couldn't be found.

```
<Errors>
    <Error>
        <errorCode>NOT_FOUND</errorCode>
         <message>Could not find a match for URL /respondentPortal/</message>
    </Error>
</Errors>
```

Not really sure where to go from here. Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you check if you have any URL Redirect Rules set-up? I tried to spin some a small service in my dev org and it is working fine. Kind of a mystery for me though.

Comment: Here is the service i added https://polyglot-developer-edition.na14.force.com/services/apexrest/poly/accounts?name=Salesforce

Comment: I did find out that you need to use the secure.force.com sub domain. The only problem is when using that, it cannot find my REST service. So

[https://fpitesters.secure.force.com/webServices/services/apexrest/respondentPortal/]https://fpitesters.secure.force.com/webServices/services/apexrest/respondentPortal/

Which should be the valid location says it cannot be found. That should be the correct location, so I'm at a bit of a loss. Almost starting to think this is a bug. Works perfectly in sandbox, fails in prod.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. Is the 'webServices' path components a namespace? (It looks like it, but the docs say that the namespace goes after /services/apexrest/) You could try with a REST method in an Apex class outside the namespace. It might be a bug when we parse the URL - the 'secure' component may be confusing the parsing code.

Comment: webServices is not a namespace. It is just the name of the site. I am not using any namespacing for this project. Who would be my best person to contact if this is indeed a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it figured out. It was due to a permissions error it seems. Somehow an object for the services profile had an impossible permission setup (it had full read write modify all on an child object where it did not have read write modify all on the parent object (an opportunity)). So fixing the permissions and making sure the service had read/write to all objects and fields it required seems to have fixed this error.

Answer (score 4):

Your production endpoint is only HTTP however.  Remember that secure Force.com site has a specific domain, so I think you need:

https://fpitesters.secure.force.com/FPITestersIndex

Comment: The lack of the s was a typo on my part. Are you able to access it from that address? I am almost starting to think there is some kind of weird redirect going on, since I did copy that address I pasted from my URL bar after going to the HTTP address. Also, attempting to access

https://fpitesters.secure.force.com/webServices/services/apexrest/respondentPortal/

said that there was no matching URL.

Comment: Another test indicates that it is indeed due to a redirect. Accessing the https version gets you back a 301 (moved permanently) which then leads to the http version. So that must be the secure subdomain you mentioned. Now I'm just not sure why the secure version says my service doesn't exist.


[Redirect](http://i.imgur.com/QfAw3.png)

Answer (score 3):

I was receiving the same error:

```
Could not find a match for URL
```

but the issue turned out to be namespacing. The Apex controller had Namespace Prefix mynamespace, with @RestResource(urlMapping='/Widgets/*'), and the URL ended up being

https://mydomain.myhost.force.com/mysitecustomurl/services/apexrest/mynamespace/Widgets/